# Convergence of Fourier series for $C^p$ functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, limits-and-convergence, harmonic-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

Let $f \in C^p[0,2\pi]$ and periodic. Denote $\omega_p$ as the moduli of continuous of $f^{(p)}$. Then
$
|f - S_Nf| \le K \frac{\log{N}}{N^p}\omega_p(2\pi/N),
$
where $S_N$ is the Fourier partial sum of order $N$, and $K$ is some constant.

I could not prove this result. Can someone help me please?

I found a similar result for the best approximation of trigonometric polynomial of order $N$, $f^*$,

of $f$ in 'An introduction to the approximation of functions' by Theodore J. Rivlin that
$
|f - f^*| \le \frac{K}{N^p}\omega_p(2\pi/N).
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem of Lebesgue that says that for a continuous periodic $f$,
$$
\|f - S_N f\|_\infty \le C \log N \|f - f^* \|_\infty.
$$
This appears as Theorem 2.2 in Rivlin's book.  Combined with the result you already know, you get what you want.

Comment: Many thanks Mark. I didn't read that far, but now I got it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not so simple, you should study the well-written 
MR0067227 (16,692a) 
Satô, Masaka
Uniform convergence of Fourier series. 
Proc. Japan Acad. 30, (1954). 528–531.

Comment: I will do that Bazin. Thanks for the suggestion.